# SEM resources from a linear model prospective

Tags: regression, references, structural-equation-modeling, linear-algebra

I'm starting a new project at work that requires theory and application of structural equation models, but my background is quite low in this area. I have a very good background in regression, linear models, and mixed effect models, and I really prefer to think about modeling as solutions to linear model matrix equations.

Are there any resources available along the lines of SEM for maxtrix algebra lovers? I do not like path diagrams ...

Answer (score 0):

This comes a little late, but [Analysis of Multivariate Social Science Data (2nd. Ed)](http://www.lse.ac.uk/Statistics/Research/Social-Statistics/Multivariate-data-analysis/Second-Edition) by Bartholomew, Steele, Moustaki, and Galbraith gets high marks for hitting some of your wishlist items according to a trusted colleague. The premise of the book is that latent variable modeling is the common thread linking across SEM approaches (factor analysis, full SEM) and MLM. I'm not sure it dives deep enough into matrix equations for you, but it is worth considering as a good start. See [review](http://www.lse.ac.uk/Statistics/Assets/Documents/C9608-ISR-DJ-Hand.pdf) by David Hand.

You may also want to consider Rabe-Hesketh & Skrondal's [Generalized Latent Variable Modeling: Multilevel, Longitudinal, and Structural Equation Models](http://www.gllamm.org/books/genlat.html). This is more mathematically rigorous and covers very similar territory.